# How to get json response in flutter using POST method?

Tags: json, flutter, dart, post

I am beginner in flutter. Please help me get and set below json data into model in flutter. I am using POST method.
'''

```
{
"success": 1,
"data": {
    "user_id": 2,
    "email": "ajay.singhal@ollosoft1.com",
    "phone": "9414905280",
    "password": "1436a615e62482ba4f075c1d4a4fd94b",
    "account_status": "Active",
    "date_of_birth": "1953-09-07T00:00:00.000Z",
    "address": "Jaipur Rajasthan",
    "profile_url": "http://18.217.236.99:4200/assets/profile_img/2/RBI-keeps-policy-rate-unchanged-1.jpg",
    "first_name": "Ajay",
    "last_name": "singhal"
}
```

}

```
'''
```

**Below is my Model class named UserInfoModel**

```
      import 'UserInfoDataModel.dart';
  
  class UserInfoModel {
    final int success;
    final UserInfoDataModel data;
  
    UserInfoModel(this.success, this.data);
  
    factory UserInfoModel.fromJson(dynamic json) {
      if (json['data'] != null) {
        var tagObjsJson = json['data'];
        UserInfoDataModel _tags =
            tagObjsJson.map((tagJson) => UserInfoDataModel.fromJson(tagJson));
  
        return UserInfoModel(json['success'] as int, _tags);
      }
    }
  
    @override
    String toString() {
      return '{${this.success}, ${this.data}}';
    }
  }
```

**Below is submodel name is UserInfoDataModel**

```
        import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
    
    class UserInfoDataModel {
      int user_id;
      String email;
      String phone;
      String password;
      String account_status;
      String date_of_birth;
      String address;
      String profile_url;
      String first_name;
      String last_name;
    
      UserInfoDataModel(
          {this.user_id,
          this.email,
          this.phone,
          this.password,
          this.account_status,
          this.date_of_birth,
          this.address,
          this.profile_url,
          this.first_name,
          this.last_name});
    
      factory UserInfoDataModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
        return UserInfoDataModel(
          user_id: json['user_id'] as int,
          email: json['email'],
          phone: json['phone'],
          password: json['password'],
          account_status: json['account_status'],
          date_of_birth: json['date_of_birth'],
          address: json['address'],
          profile_url: json['profile_url'],
          first_name: json['first_name'],
          last_name: json['last_name'],
        );
      }
    }
```

**My APi Call is below Using POST Method**
**I am successfully getting response, but unable to set in model**

```
         UserInfoModel _userInfoModel;
      UserInfoDataModel _userInfoDataModel;
    
      String url = BaseURLHeaders().getBaseURl() + "userInfo";
      Map headers = BaseURLHeaders().getHeader();
    
      @override
      void initState() {
        // TODO: implement initState
        super.initState();
        getData();
      }
    
      Future<UserInfoModel> getData() async {
        String user_id = "1";
        var mapData = new Map<String, dynamic>();
        mapData['user_id'] = user_id;
        // mapData['first_name'] = firstName;
    
        var response = await http.post(
          url,
          headers: headers,
          body: mapData,
        );
        setState(() {
          print("userInfoDetails: ${response.body}");
          print("urlTop: ${url}");
          print("headersTop: ${headers}");
          print("responseCode: ${response.statusCode}");
        });
    
        if (response.statusCode == 200) {
          var res = json.decode(response.body);
          _userInfoModel = UserInfoModel.fromJson(res);
          if (_userInfoModel.success == 1) {
            var data = res["data"];
    
            setState(() {
              print("responseBody: ${res}");
              print("userInfoSuccess: ${_userInfoModel.success}");
              print("dataVaalue: ${data["email"]}");
              print("urlBelow: ${url}");
              print("headersBelow: ${headers}");
            });
          }
        }
      }
```

Comment: Please add what you have tried and where you are need help.

Comment: @NidheeshMT Please see my code which i updated above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 UserInfoDataModel _tags =
            tagObjsJson.map((tagJson) => UserInfoDataModel.fromJson(tagJson));
```

here you are actually treated tagObjsJson as a list. but it is a JsonObject so there you don't want the `map` function.

you can access the object as

```
UserInfoDataModel _tags =UserInfoDataModel.fromJson(tagJson);
```

Comment: Really big Thank to @Nidheesh MT, its working now. You are such a great person, Thank you so much buddy.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [json_serializer](https://pub.dev/packages/json_serializable) in flutter. See [flutter docs](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/json).
If you use IntelliJ IDEA, you can use [DartToJson](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/12562-jsontodart-json-to-dart-) package. It generates automatically for you and you can use `fromJson` and `toJson` method.